# How to build a URL Query Strings with jQuery from content in multiple items using class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am trying to build a URL that can be used in an iframe from content that's on a page. There are URL queries in that the paramaters can be passed into.

so I'm hoping to build a url like http://www.example.com/iframe.aspx?title=&itemnum=&

The other catch is there are multiple itemNum's that need to be comma separated like Item1,Item2 and also titles like Title1,Title2

Here is a n00bular start to this:

```
<div id="options">
    <h2>Options</h2>
    <div class="grid">
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="box">
                        <span class="item-number">Item1</span>
                        <span class="title">Title1</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="box">
                        <span class="item-number">Item2</span>
                        <span class="title">Title2</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

    // Page Variables for iFrame URL
    var itemNum = $('.item-number').html();
    var itemTitle = $('.title').html();

    // Build Params
    var params = { itemnum:$itemNum, title:$itemTitle };

    // Variable for full Query Strings
    var mapQs = jQuery.param( params );

    // Build Full URL root + query strings
    $( "iframe" ).src ( 'http://www.blah.com/' + mapQs );

</script>
```

Comment: Is expected result `?Item1=Title1`, `?Item2=Title2`? Or, `?itemnum=Item1&title=Title1`?

Comment: expected result would be:

Comment: https://www. blah.com/page.aspx?=Item1,Item2&title=Title1,Title2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the jQuery .param( JSON ) function, it will join the objects and url encode them.

**EDIT**: I've updated the code to meet the OP's needs, I've also built this into a function so that way the code can look a little cleaner by leaving the selector strings in the `params` object.

I've left comments to explain the code but basically it loops though all the properties in the `params` json object, then makes that property an array and adds all elements' inner html to that array

```js
function makeIFrameURI(){
  // Build Params
  var params = {
    "itemnum": '.item-number',
    "title": '.title'
  };

  //loop through the properties of the params object
  for(prop in params){
    var selector = params[prop]; //get the selector
    params[prop] = []; //equal blank array
    $(selector).each(function(){
      //add the individual element inner html into the 
      params[prop].push($(this).html());
    });
  }

  //loop through the properties of the params object
  for(prop in params){
    //make comma separated list
    var tmp = params[prop].join(",");
    params[prop] = tmp;
  }

  var queryString = '?' + $.param(params);
  var myURI = 'http://www.blah.com/' + queryString;
  return myURI;
}

var iframeURI = makeIFrameURI();
//$( "iframe" ).src ( iframeURI );
$('#result').html(iframeURI);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="options">
    <h2>Options</h2>
    <div class="grid">
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="box">
                        <span class="item-number">Item1</span>
                        <span class="title">Title1</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="box">
                        <span class="item-number">Item2</span>
                        <span class="title">Title2</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<pre id="result"></pre>
```

**EDIT**: I just wanted to mention that the jQuery function `$.params()` will urlencode the arguments, this is desired if you're using it as a URI. In almost all case you would be using the parameters server side e.g. in your PHP. So on the PHP page you were using them, you would retrieve the value using `$_GET[]` which would automatically decode the values. so on the page if you did this code in your php
    echo var_dump($_GET);

it would show this value:

```
array(2) { ["itemnum"]=> string(11) "Item1,Item2" ["title"]=> string(13) "Title1,Title2" }
```

Comment: You need `?` before `queryString`

Comment: This is great thanks so much. The problem is I'm not actually trying to pull the class name ".item-number" instead I'm hoping that can retreive the inner html (content) of every .item-number on the page. In this case that would be Item1 and Item2 thus that URL query would be (?itemnum=Item1,Item2)

Comment: Thanks that works great. Thanks so much for your help. Last question... how can I make them come up as comma's and not %2 ?

Comment: Nevermind I got it - var myURI = decodeURIComponent('http://www.blah.com/' + queryString;) Thanks for your help! - Maybe add that part?

Comment: the `$.params()` function will url encode it, if you're making that the url of an iframe it is desired and best practice to have it url encoded so it will pass all the parameter values properly. Furthermore in almost all cases you would be handling the parameters server side using `$_GET['']` in which case php will automatically decode them.